# Cannot invoke a stored procedure due to missing user rights

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-grant

I try to invoke a stored procedure within another SP.  The "inner" (invoked) SP returns to the invoking procedure a temp table. That works in management studio after I have replaced the single hashtags by two preceeding hashtags for temptables, but in reporting services I still get the error message that user rigths are not granted.  Why is the reporting server environment interpreting the rights differently ? Does anyone have a clue ?

Comment: You can't "return" a temporary table from a procedure so that doesn't make a lot of sense, and using global temporary tables  is rarely the correct idea. This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) if I am honest.

Comment: It works for me. To be more precisely I insert the returned single datasets from the "subordinated" procedure with a cursor into a temporary table of the invoking procedure.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: You can use EXECUTE AS to impersonate another user and run a procedure (need admin access to do this) to test your issue in SSMS. Will say in general, I recommend against passing temp tables into nested stored procedures as it leads to these tricky debug scenarios. Much better to encapsulate the logic in a view/table-valued function and have both procs call the same function. Doesn't repeat code and is much easier to manage/debug

Comment: As others have said, this is not a great idea... Anyway,  you cannot create a *proper* #temp table in the 'child' procedure and 'return' it to the calling parent proc, you just can't.. This only works for you because you changed it to use global ##temp tables (which are bad news generally). You can create the #temp table in the parent proc, then get the child proc to populate it, it will be visible to the parent proc as you expect. If you still have problems, then check what credentials the datasource is using to connect to the database server, this might not be the current user's credentials.